# python re match strings not ending with word

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match all strings **not** ending with a specific word. 
For some reason the following doesn't work:

```
>> import re
>> my_str = 'static/assets/img/favicon.ico'
>> re.search('^static.+(?!ico)$', my_str)
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7f08b9773440>
```

Can you please explain why it's not working and how to fix it?

Comment: Why not just `if not my_str.endswith('.ico')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what `str.endswith()` is for.

```
if my_str.endswith('ico'):
     # do stuff
```

And if you are dealing with file names you can use [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) module which provides support for Unix shell-style wildcards:

```
import fnmatch
for name in file names:
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.ico'):
         #do stuff
```

And if you want to check that your string stats with a specific pattern you can use `str.startswith()` method alongside the `str.endswith()` :

```
if my_str.startswith('static') and my_str.endswith('ico'):
        #do stuff
```

Comment: can you show to correct way to do it with re? because it also needs to start with 'static'

Comment: @DavidTzoor That's what anubhava showed, but it's not a pyhtonic way at all. In terms of runtime using `fnmatch` and `endswith` will performs too much faster for huge data sets.

Comment: so use `startswith` and `endswith`?

Answer (score 10):

I think you want to use a negative lookbehind, not lookahead.

```
^static.+$(?<!ico)
```

See [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jN1kL6/1) if this is what you needed.

---

`(?!ico)$` or `$(?!ico)` would look if there is not `ico` after the end which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
print re.search(r'^(?!.*ico$)static.+', my_str)
None
```

`(?!.*ico$)` asserts that string doesn't end with `ico`

Comment: but that's not what I wanted. I need the string to start with static and not end with ico

Comment: You're mistaken as this is what this regex is already doing i.e. matching a string starting with `static` and NOT ending with `ico`